Data Factory - Change Data Capture doesn't write data into SQL Server
I have an source Azure SQL Server db (S1) with CDC enabled and I need to publish the data changes from a specific table to a destination Azure SQL Server db (D1).
I update a row in the source and in the "monitor" I see "changes read 1", "changes written 1" but no data is copied to the destination.

Just for the sake of testing I configured the destination to be an Azure Storage Blob and I see data being created there. In this case it works as expected, data flows properly from source to the destination
Does the destination Azure SQL Server db needs a special configuration?

can you add error you are getting?

I see no error, I see: Changes Read 1, Changes written 1

I learned that "Change Data Capture" available under Factory Resources works ok, but after an initial load. So there are 2 strategies when there is already some data in the Source:

Use a "Copy Activity" to perform the initial load in the destination and then use the "Change Data Capture"
OR
Use a regular data flow in a pipeline with the "Full on first run, then incremental" run mode

